# Get mapping from profile in AutoMapper for unit test

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to write a test for my inherited profile class:

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
  public MyProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<SomeModelDto, SomeModel>();
  }
}
```

Test:

```cs
[Test]
public void AutoMapper_MyProfileMapping_IsValid()
{
  // arrange
  var profile = new MyProfile();

  // act
  var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(profile)));

  // assert
  configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

How can I test that my profile is containing all necessary maps? Do I generally need to check something like this?

greetings

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/7eb7e4208bc8f94cf5d7eb6d39f7dd4bd352b13d/src/UnitTests/IMappingExpression/IncludeMembers.cs#L46) is an example.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu for the example. "One of the inspirations behind AutoMapper was to eliminate not just the custom mapping code, but eliminate the need for manual testing. Because the mapping from source to destination is convention-based, you will still need to test your configuration." (see [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html)). So I don't want to test if every property was mapped correctly. The only missing thing is that the profile is containing all expected mappings.

Comment: That _only_ applies when your config is just `CreateMap` and nothing else. Otherwise you wrote some code that needs to be tested :) I didn't say you need to check _all_ properties. Configuration validation already reports missing maps, so that's already covered.